# Was the Crown of Durin real?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, dwarves, first-age

According to the myth of the settlement of Khazad-Dum, Durin saw the crown in Mirrormere and took it as a sign:

> A group of seven stars mysteriously reflected from the surface of the lake of Kheled-zâram (also called the Mirrormere), even when the Sun was shining in the sky above the lake. In the ancient days of the First Age, they were glimpsed by Durin the Deathless, who took them as a sign to settle in the Misty Mountains that rose above the lake, and so Khazad-dûm was founded.
>
> From the glyphweb [article on the Crown of Durin](https://www.glyphweb.com/arda/c/crownofdurin.php)

Was the crown something that really happened and if so, how did it happen? Was it e.g. a Valar or other entity that sent it as a sign to Durin to settle there? I think it is a rather big coincidence that Durin saw this, decided to settle and it was (AFAIK) the only place where mithril could be found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three members of the Fellowship of the Ring - Frodo, Sam and Gimli - see the crown at the beginning of the chapter 'Lothlorien'. Gimli clearly knew about it beforehand. Clearly it is a real phenomenon, in-universe. What causes it is unknown, as far as I am aware. I am also unaware of any evidence to suggest that the foundation of Moria was influenced by the crown. The poem recited by Gimli in 'A Journey in the Dark' says Durin saw it, but that's all.

Moria certainly existed as far back as the Age of the Trees (Silmarillion, chapter 10: 'Of the Sindar'). The information we have concerning Middle-earth at this time is focused on Beleriand; we know almost nothing about the founding of Moria.

Comment: Most likely, someone (not necessarily Durin) noticed the reflection at some later point *after* Moria was settled, and decided it would make a nice origin story. That said, it's would fit the mythology for Aulë to ask Varda to place some stars just so, so that Durin would see them (after some diving prompting to explore the area around Moria).

Answer (score 7):

This may reflect Tolkien re-purposing a scientific error made by Aristotle, who immortalized an old wives' tale claiming that it was possible to see the stars during the day if you were at the bottom of a deep chasm or well. This claim was taken seriously until Alexander von Humboldt performed extensive experiments to debunk it in the 19th century.

In Middle Earth this phenomenon is apparently real, and the Mirrormere is in a dale or valley, the depth of which makes the stars visible as a reflection in the lake.

Comment: Tolkien definitely believed in this misconception about seeing the stars during the daytime from the bottom of a narrow shaft or defile.  The phenomenon is described unambiguously later on (near the end of "The Passage of the Gray Company," I believe).

Comment: @Buzz --- and I thought I remembered every obscure detail of LotR!

Comment: Actually there were one or more questions about LOTR a few years ago that I answered, where seeing stars in daylight and other feats were mentioned.

Comment: And here is a link to the question and answer I mentioned: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94922/how-can-tolkiens-characters-see-stars-during-the-daytime/95023#95023

Comment: @Buzz All you really know is that Tolkien liked the idea well enough that he used it in LotR. ...he described quite a few phenomena in LotR which don't seem to happen in our world. It seems unlikely he believed them all to be true here, as well.

Answer (score 2):

"The Song of Durin", *The Fellowship of the Ring*, Book II, Chapter 4, "A Journey in the Dark".

> He stooped and looked in Mirrormere,
>
> And saw a crown of stars appear,
>
> As gems upon a silver thread,
>
> Above the shadow of his head.

and:

> But still the sunken stars appear
>
> In dark and windless Mirrormere;
>
> There lies his crown in water deep,
>
> Till Durin wakes again from sleep.

Frodo, Sam, and Gimli saw the stars appear in Mirrormere, so apparently anyone could see the Crown of Durin in the waters.

In my opinion the crown of Durin was an illusion, a real illusion, created by some form of what we call "magic".  It may have been created by Aulë to show Durin that this was the place to settle, or just for the joy of creation.

I don't think that even a Vala could make a set of seven stars hover in the proper formation in a place in the sky where they would always be reflected from one single lake in the world, and from no other lake, whenever someone looked into that right lake.

And putting seven star-like underwater lights in the proper formation in the lake would be a lot easier, but the lake wasn't a tiny pond, and possible places for people to look in the lake might have been separated by kilometers or miles.  So having the seven lights zoom in formation into position wherever people were looking in the lake might create large waves which splash the onlookers, and possibly wash them into the lake to drown.  And what if different people looked in the lake from widely separated places at the same time?

So it had to be some "magical" illusion of seven stars in a crown-like shape appearing in the waters whenever and wherever someone looked into the lake.

And see this question and answers:

[How can Tolkien's characters see stars during the daytime?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94922/how-can-tolkiens-characters-see-stars-during-the-daytime/95023#95023)